# How to nicely load an object from the builder.configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, appsettings

I am working on a .NET Core Web API using Swagger with multiple Swagger endpoints inside. But my programs.cs becomes a bit crowded with the many `options.SwaggerDoc("endpoint-name", more stuff... { ... even more stuff });` lines of code. But I need multiple endpoints as I have several services that all share the same data context, but I want to provide them as six different services. And this works fine! No problems here...
But I want the programs.cs to look cleaner by loading some information from the configuration file. Especially the 'License' and 'contact' with every endpoint as I don't want those hard-coded in my code. They need to be in the config.
So I need to have multiple `OpenApiContact` and `OpenApiLicense` records inside the `appsettings.json` and read them through the `builder.Configuration` to put them in the proper position. After all, this information needs to be configurable.
If the answer is to do something like:

```
var contact = new OpenApiContact
{
    Name = builder.Configuration["Service1:Name"],
    Email = builder.Configuration["Service1:Email"],
    Url = new Uri(builder.Configuration["Service1:Url"])
};
```

Then I'll be very unhappy... It pollutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage build in [configuration binding mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern) (cleaned up json config):

```json
{
  "Service1": {
    "Name": "qwewq",
    "Url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    "Email": "test@email.com"
  }
}
```

```cs
var contact = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Service1").Get<OpenApiContact>();
```

Or even binding to dictionary/array. For example with dictionary:

```json
{
  "Services": {
    "Service1": {
      "Name": "qwewq",
      "Url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
      "Email": "test@email.com"
    }
  }
}
```

```cs
var openApiContacts = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Services").Get<Dictionary<string, OpenApiContact>>();
```

Comment: Yep. After posting the Q, I discovered this myself. :) And answered my own Q.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was simpler than expected. Just started trying and it worked! I now have this:

```
options.SwaggerDoc("Service1", builder.Configuration.GetSection("Swagger:Service1").Get<OpenApiInfo>());
```

And it loads the whole OpenApiInfo from the configuration. And inside the configuration I have this:

```
  "Swagger": {
    "Service1": {
      "Title": "Some title",
      "Description": "Some description.",
      "Contact": {
        "Name": "W.A. ten Brink",
        "Email": "wim.tenbrink@example.com",
        "Url": "https://www.example.com"
      },
      "License": {
        "Name": "Example",
        "Url": "https://www.example.com/License/"
      },
      "Version": "1.0.0.1"
    },
...[more]...
```

And all the API information is now loaded from the configuration file. All this information is just informational so the administrators can change it if they like. If they misspell the service name or whatever then the endpoint is still there. It just has no information.